# 2017 Visual C++ compiler is not detected for Windows SDK 8.1

Tags: visual-c++, cross-compiling, simulink

I have a library in Simulink that I must use and it is dependent on 8.1 SDK. I removed Windows 10 SDK from my Windows 10 OS. Using Visual Studio Installer, I uninstalled SDK 10, and installed 8.1. However the VC++ 17 compiler isn't detected by the system (cl in command line) and by the mex engine in Matlab.  When I install VC++ 15, it is detected when running vcvarsall.bat , but not VC++ 17.

My top level model needs to use VC++ 17, so I can't recompile everything in VC++ 15.

Is is even possible to compile with VC++ 17 using Windows SDK 8.1 ?

Comment: It is an anachronism, VS2017 did not yet exist when 8.1 was released.  It is the VS2017 installer that needs to recognize 8.1.  Try repair first.

Comment: I did try that. It didn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

> Is is even possible to compile with VC++ 17 using Windows SDK 8.1 ?

Yes this is definitely possible. In VS2017 go to the solution explorer. Right-click on your project(s) and click `Retarget Projects`. Here you can specify target SDK for your project. You can also retarget the whole solution in a similar manner.

You can also check (and change) your currently used SDK under `Project properties` - `General` - `Windows SDK version`.